# Grabbing data from an XML stream using jsoup

Tags: java, xml, jsoup

Im trying to get the 'Done' from between these tags in an XML stream

```
<scan_run_status>Done</scan_run_status>
```

This is the code I'm using but it returns nothing.

I am picking up `id` and `status` in the same way no problem.

input1 contains the xml string

```
status = Jsoup.parse(input1).getAllElements().attr("scan_run_status");

System.out.println(status);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input1);
/* Grab all elements named "scan_run_sttus" */
Elements els = doc.select("scan_run_status");
/* If you need the first only ...here it is..*/
String status = els.first().text();
/* Otherwise you can loop 
for (Element el: els) {
   //.Do something
}
*/
```

and don't forget to do all the checks if els is empty etc. etc.

[Here](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax) you can found all the tips about JSoup selector.

Comment: Just the job - Thanks alot